# Does `git branch remotes/origin/foo` create a new branch?

Tags: git

I was under master branch, and run `git branch -ra` which shows a branch

```
remotes/origin/deals
```

The branch isn't shown in the output of `git branch`. 
I guess that it is a remote-tracking branch, correct?

I wanted to switch to that branch, but I accidentally ran

```
$ git branch remotes/origin/deals
$ git branch
* master
  remotes/origin/deals
```

Is it correct that i should have ran `git branch -b remotes/origin/deals` instead?

Did I create a new branch whose name is also `remotes/origin/deals`, and are there now two branches whose names are both `remotes/origin/deals` and how is that possible?

If I created a new branch `remotes/origin/deals`, is it a local branch? how can I remove it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

When you ran

```
$ git branch remotes/origin/deals
```

...you created a new file:

```
# file describing local branch created by the above command
.git/logs/refs/heads/remotes/origin/deals
```

...which, indeed, you should probably delete (either by hand, or with `git branch -d remotes/origin/deals`).

This is as opposed to the file pointing to the *remote* branch head:

```
# file created by fetching from the remote branch
.git/logs/refs/remotes/origin/deals
```

---

To check out a remote branch, you should use:

```
$ git checkout remotes/origin/deals
```

...or, to create and checkout a local branch which tracks that remote branch:

```
$ git checkout -b deals --track origin/deals
```

Answer (score 1):

`git branch remotes/origin/deals` creates a new branch called remotes/origin/deals

`git checkout -b remotes/origin/deals`
creates a new branch called remotes/origin/deals and points to that branch

`git checkout remotes/origin/deals`
points to an existing branch called remotes/origin/deals

`git branch -d remotes/origin/deals`
safely deletes the branch making sure there is no uncommitted work

`git branch -D remotes/origin/deals`
forcefully deletes the branch

`git push origin --delete {the_remote_branch}`
deletes the remote branch

Answer (score 1):

If you want switch on a remote branch you need :
git checkout branchname .

Now you has created a branch with same name of remote branch .
A simple solution could be to clone your project on a different local folder . After this you can run :
**git checkout remotes/origin/deals** .

Answer (score 1):

The answers you have gotten so far are all correct, but are not pointing out a key distinction.  As you saw in another question, Git declares that there are two "kinds" of branches, regular (local) branches and *remote-tracking* branches.

Under the hood, however, Git actually unifies these—and tags, too—by lumping them all together under the general category of *references*.  So this brings up a good question:  How does Git decide that *B* is a local branch and *R* is a remote-tracking branch?

The obvious answer is actually the wrong answer!

The `git branch` command, when run with no flags or with `-l`, shows local branches:

```
$ git branch
master
test
```

Or, when run with `-r`, it shows remote-tracking branches:

```
$ git branch -r
origin/master
origin/test
```

You might say to yourself: *Aha, `origin` means "remote-tracking"*.  But this isn't true, and in fact, when you run `git branch -a` to see both local *and* remote-tracking branches, the output changes:

```
$ git branch -a
master
test
remotes/origin/master
remotes/origin/test
```

Now it's a bit more mysterious.  Maybe `remotes/origin` means remote-tracking?  Well, that's closer, but still not right.

#### How Git distinguishes local and remote-tracking branches

In fact, `git branch` is lying to you, with a good excuse: it's trying to shorten things.  The *full* name of each reference starts with `refs/`.  If `git branch` did not do this shortening, you would see:

```
refs/heads/master
refs/heads/test
refs/remotes/origin/master
refs/remotes/origin/test
```

Now the obvious answer is the correct answer: *A local branch starts with `refs/heads/` and a remote-tracking branch starts with `refs/remotes/`.*  (For completeness, let's also note that a tag starts with `refs/tags/`.)  The `git branch` command shortens these, with the idea that you know what kind of branch you're looking for because you either asked for local branches or for remote-tracking branches.

#### The same goes for branch creation

The `git branch` command applies the same rules to branch *creation*.  If you use `-l` or no flag at all, it creates a regular (local) branch: it puts `refs/heads/` in front of whatever you typed in.  If you use `-r`, it creates a remote-tracking branch: it puts `refs/remotes/` in front.  Then, as usual, it strips those off again when it shows them to you.

What this means is that `git branch remotes/origin/deals` creates `refs/heads/remotes/origin/deals`: a *local* branch, not a remote-tracking branch.  It then shows up as `remotes/origin/deals` after stripping off `refs/heads/`.  It's sometimes impossible to tell this apart from an actual remote-tracking branch `refs/remotes/origin/deals`, so **if you actually had both** the name would be somewhat ambiguous.<sup>1</sup>  Since you don't, though, it's not ambiguous: it's just a local branch, with a very misleading name.

#### Diagnostic tools

The "plumbing" command `git for-each-ref` will, as its default action, print every reference—branches, remote-tracking branches, tags, "notes", the "stash": in short, *everything* under `refs/`—by full name.  If you're in this ambiguous-reference situation, you can get a full dump of everything using `git for-each-ref`.

For a nicer (higher level) view, `git branch` with appropriate flags, and/or with various color options set, will split up the names.  If `git branch -l` (or `git branch` with no flags) shows a branch name, it's local, even if it starts with `origin/` or `remotes/origin/`.  If `git branch -r` shows a branch name, it's a remote-tracking branch.  With color mode turned on, local branches default to plain, except for the current branch which is printed in green; and remote-tracking branches are printed in red.  Adding multiple `v` flags (e.g., `git branch -avv`), you get additional information, with "upstream" names printed in blue.  (Upstreams are most often remote-tracking branches, since these are the ones Git creates automatically, but you *can* set one local branch as the upstream for another local branch.)

---

<sup>1</sup>Git deals with this by choosing one according to Git's internal rules.  These rules are described in [the `gitrevisions` documentation](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gitrevisions.html), but there is an important caveat: the `git checkout` command uses its own, different, rules.  So `git diff` or `git log` will show one thing, while `git checkout` will do another, in some ambiguous-name cases.  It's best just to avoid the situation entirely.